# Triggering chart animation on Hover - easyPieChart

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I have 6 charts

```
$('.chart-1').hover(function(e) {
    $('.chart-1').easyPieChart({
        lineCap: 'square',
        lineWidth: '4',
        barColor: '#E81F4D',
        size: '40',
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });
    $('.chart-1').data('easyPieChart').enableAnimation();
});


$('.chart-2').hover(function(e) {
    $('.chart-2').easyPieChart({

        lineCap: 'square',
        lineWidth: '4',
        barColor: '#971FE8',
        size: '40',
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });

});

$('.chart-3').hover(function(e) {
    $('.chart-3').easyPieChart({

        lineCap: 'square',
        lineWidth: '4',
        barColor: '#1F8CE8',
        size: '40',
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });

});


$('.chart-4').hover(function(e) {
    $('.chart-4').easyPieChart({

        lineCap: 'square',
        lineWidth: '4',
        barColor: '#1AB356',
        size: '40',
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });

});


$('.chart-5').hover(function(e) {
    $('.chart-5').easyPieChart({

        lineCap: 'square',
        lineWidth: '4',
        barColor: '#EDE20E',
        size: '40',
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });
});


$('.chart-6').hover(function(e) {
    $('.chart-6').easyPieChart({

        lineCap: 'square',
        lineWidth: '4',
        barColor: '#FC7402',
        size: '40',
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });
});
```

I want to trigger the animation when user hover on it, I've tried above codes, and still not working some how.

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: No idea where it is failing?  If you console.log($(this.el)); what do you see?

Comment: The actual issue is this `onStep: function(from, to, percent) {` I had to remove that and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be silly, but all you need is animation right ?

First one, you have to declare the chart with animate parameter, so it has delay.
second off all, you have to create on hover event. Then it looks like this

(I'm just gonna give one example)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/javascripts/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="https://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/stylesheets/jquery.easy-pie-chart.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="chart" data-percent="73">73%</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
$('.chart').easyPieChart({
        animate: 1000
    });
    
$('.chart').mouseenter(() => {
    $('.chart').data('easyPieChart').update(0);
    $('.chart').data('easyPieChart').update(parseInt($('.chart')[0].dataset.percent));
})
```

This is the sample : https://jsfiddle.net/9wuog48m/

Comment: Where do I specify my options for my chart ?  Can you update your answer to include that ?

Comment: at line that starts with `$('.chart').easyPieChart`, thats where the options belong. You can read the documentation for further options https://www.javascripting.com/view/easy-pie-chart

Comment: The actual issue is this `onStep: function(from, to, percent) {` I had to remove that and it works.